# Blurring without transparency between two pictures or any other better way

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, blur

I have two pictures of the same size (e.g. 8192x8192):

[image]

[image]

Using Photoshop I put the first one on the second one and make the color matching. Then I add a mask layer and use a gradiend tool to make a smooth transition between with two pictures (e.q. from the left side). I get:

[image]

But I really don't like the transparency:

[image]

So maybe there is any better way to make a smooth transition between these two pictures?:

[image]

Just to minimize this sharp border. Without transparency.

**Added:**

Using transparency in my attempt is good if we look at the third picture from a large distance. But this picture is a surface texture (for a free space flight simulator) which should be viewed closely as well, but in this case (look at the fourth picture) I don't like that the highly detailed texture is shining through the lowly detailed one. So, I would like to try any other way without transparency, even if the texture blending will not be as good as using transparency. One of my ideas is blurring only the highly detailed texture with variable pixelation like:

[image]

So, I made such three selections and applied the Gaussian blurring to them with radius 18, 9, and 4, respectively. The result is better now:

[image]

And from close:

[image]

Maybe there's a tool to make a such gradient blur without transparency:

[image]

By the way, the border between those highly and lowly detailed textures doesn't have to be a straight line, it can be a curved line too.

Comment: The *only* other option besides using transparency, would be to blur *both* image at the seam.. but that's going to cause the blurry side to appear *more* blurry. To be honest.. I don't understand what the issue is with using transparency. If it's creating too much blur eating away the clear side.. use less blur/a more defined mask.

Comment: What is the problem your image is trying to solve. That should get a unsight into how this should be solved.

Comment: @Scott, thanks. I added some explanation to my question.

Comment: @joojaa, thanks. I added some explanation to my question, hope it will help

Comment: so basically your asking us how to do manual mipmapping?

Comment: @joojaa, honestly I don't think so, I'm just trying to make a smooth transition between two textures without using transparency.

Comment: @misha.physics ok its just that had this been a mipmapin for 3D zooms then you would have gotten superior results by mipmapping which your 3D engine needs to do anyway (just a inferior one). Less memory usage and better results  and ultimately all your problems would have gone away, but okay not then.

Comment: @joojaa, honestly I don't know how MIP mapping could help me with this. There's a global Earth texture in low resolution, and I'm making a local highly detailed area for a base. So, I'm trying to minimize the sharp border between these global and local textures. Well, it seems blurring with transparency is the best way so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you merely want to reduce the obvious line between the two images, then I think you could use a Levels adjustment on one of the images to make the contrast difference less obvious.

An example

[image]

If the sharp line is still an issue, then perhaps only apply a little blurring with a feathered selection of the edge

[image]

Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have just tried these two ways right now. And also added some explanation to my started post.